# LINQ to XML Speed

Tags: c#, performance, datetime, linq-to-xml

Quick question, the following line should be pretty self explanatory :

```
doc.Descendants("DOB").Select(dob => dob.ToString()).All(dob => DateTime.Parse(dob.ToString()) != DateTime.Parse(processing.DateOfBirth))
```

But just in case, I want to return false if any value of node (DOB) is the same datetime as 
processing.dateofbirth, because i'll need to add the date of birth to the xml if it's not in there.

My two questions are

**Is this the shortest amount of code to accomplish this, with linq to xml?** (i think it's not)

and

**This will be run against several million records, is there a more efficient way to accomplish this?**

EDIT

I miscommunicated, sorry.  The XML is small.  There are millions of rows in a database representing a single person, with a column PersonXml that just has name, dob, number, and a few other things. The rows are read in through a SqlDataReader and validated/updated, this being part of that.

Comment: Linq to Xml is not fast. Show a xml file

Comment: _"This will be run against several million records, is there a more efficient way to accomplish this?"_ Maybe consider a database instead of a ginormous XML file that you would have to iterate millions of records? Or at least consider reading in _all_ the XML content once, build lookup collections (dictionaries and the sort) against properties you need to find fast. EDIT: _Especially_ if you perform all the `DateTime` parsing _once_ on load and not again, and again, and again each time you iterate.

Comment: Based on your edit, does the `PersonXml` represent just a simple small bit of XML data? Something on the scale of `<person><dob>01/02/1980</dob><name>Bob</name><number>1</number><fewotherthings>...</fewotherthings></person>`?

Comment: Then no, it won't really matter how you parse it. Have you tried running your task and measuring how much time it takes? Likely with something _that_ small, you're splitting hairs with parsing time. EDIT: Although if you only want to see if _any_ `dob` equals `processingDOB`, then consider using `Any()` instead of `All()`. `Any()` will return `true/false` if any match and stop iterating. `All()` will check of _all_ of them happen to match.

Comment: Also, I'm assuming `processing.DateOfBirth` is essentially a constant defined outside or before this method call. Consider performing its `DateTime.Parse` first outside the iteration rather than reparsing it each time it checks/iterates.

Comment: The first `dob.ToString()` can become `dob.Value`, the second can be just `dob`.

Comment: It really depends here on how you are using this code. If it is a column in the database, I suspect you are pulling the table into memory and parsing the XML there since EF and L2S don't support LINQ to XML converting to XQuery in the database directly. For your performance concerns, we would need to see how you are interacting with the database and using that information in your LINQ to XML query. You may need a storedproc here for a direct XQuery on the column. Alternatively, you may need to denormalize the table including these elements as columns.

Answer (score 0):

1) Not sure here, at least I cant think of a shorter way to write it.

2) If the format is always the same, you could consider working on the data directly. Either work on the string or on a stream directly. Parsing the string to XDoc will always cut its share. You mentioned the xml file is very small and might not change.

For a project where I am writing a xml file that is way to large to keep in memory, I have written a class (actually found parts of that code on SO) that works on a filestream and looks for matching patterns byte by byte. In your case this might be bad style and a bit unconvenient to work with, but if speed is a matter this will beat XDocument anytime.

**-edit-** Reading your edits, I think speed is not really something you are too concerned about and this is a task you might have to do only once to correct some old data? In that case I'd suggest you just stick with your solution, maybe use a Taskfactory to spawn threads that run a new task for each row you receive from the db and let it run over night. In my mind the easiest and safest solution

Comment: Have you compared your class against the XStreamingElement implementation - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xstreamingelement.aspx

Comment: @JimWooley afaik XStreamingElement will write xml data to a stream? This did not help in my case because I had to read huge xml files, find occurences of something and insert something else at these places.